# zXing: Unable to read a valid QR code

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, decode, qr-code, zxing

I'm using zXing C# library to decode QR code in my winforms application in VS 2010. It works fine for some images, but fails for a few.

**exception message :**

> "Exception of type 'com.google.zxing.ReaderException' was thrown."

**here is my code :**

***Code for the function that returns the decoded data***

```
    public string GetQRValue(Bitmap value)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            QRCodeReader reader = new QRCodeReader();
            //com.google.zxing.Reader re
            com.google.zxing.LuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(value, value.Width, value.Height);
            var binarizer = new HybridBinarizer(source);
            var binBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(binarizer);
            result = reader.decode(binBitmap).Text;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            result = ex.Message; //string.Empty;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

***Code that calls the above function :***

```
Bitmap image1 = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(txtFile.Text , true);
lblData.Text = cls.GetQRValue(image1);
```

Here txtFile is the path to the file, and cls is a object of the class that contains the decoding function.

***Following is the image that fails to decode.***

[image: Qr code that fails to decode]
I've tried tried decoding it at the following website. And is decoded there.
http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/qrgen/

***And the following image is decoded successfully.***

[image: Qr code that decoded successfully]

Please help me to solve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C# port is somewhat old and not maintained. It looks like either a problem with your binarization, or some problem in the port, since the main branch (Java) decodes these fine:

http://zxing.org/w/decode?u=http%3A%2F%2Fi.stack.imgur.com%2FTEiIH.jpg&full=true
http://zxing.org/w/decode?u=http%3A%2F%2Fi.stack.imgur.com%2FP8irV.png&full=true

Comment: :: Then what should I do? Any suggestion to make my program accurate?